# Is there any chance to store many variables without array?

Tags: c, arrays, variables

I wanna get some numbers from keyboard. But how to store that number without array[] ? Have i chance to do that ? I don't know exact how many numbers come from keyboard. If i had permission of array, its simple. But array is not allowed.

Comment: Can you use pointer ?

Comment: Permission? Linked lists maybe?

Comment: i can use everything, but arrays is not allowed only :))

Comment: Are you sure that you need C? Not C++? In C++, you can easily use data structures like `std::vector`.

Comment: i need a very very clumsy method to do this :)) without any instant functions blahblah. :D

Comment: @Cool As Collin said take a look at linked list . This is what you need .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, I'd still go with arrays, but if you insist on using pointers, this code below will help you. Regardless of whether you need arrays or pointers, you still need to define an upper limit on how many elements can be stored in memory.

It is now up to you to modify the code to make it efficient and pretty to your assignment needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int numelements=10;
    int curelement=0;
    int* data=calloc(1,numelements*sizeof(int));
    int* p=data;
    int* res=data;

    while (curelement < numelements){
    scanf("%d",p);
    if (*p==0){break;} //exit if number entered is zero.
    p++;
    curelement++;
    }
    //print results
    while(*res != 0){
      printf("%d ",*res);
      res++;
    }
    free(data);
    return 0;
}
```